# Выцепить имя кнопки и обратиться к ней

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, pywinauto

Пытаюсь выцепить, как обратиться к кнопе сохранить, которая представлена в виде значка синей дискеты.

Окно таблицы:
[image: Окно и стрелка на кнопку которую пытаюсь выцепить]
*AutoIt Window Info (x64)* в панели видит только три объекта `TToolBar` и в нём `Edit` и `TDBNavigator`.

Попытка использования сочетания клавиш(Ctrl + s) через код для вызова окна сохранения не удалась. Руками использовав сочетания окно место сохранения появилось.

```
app = Application(backend="win32")
app.start(r"C:\1\1.exe")

...

dlg = app.TfmTblWTP2
dlg.set_focus()
sleep(2)
dlg.type_keys("^s", set_foreground=False)
dlg.TBitBtn0.click() # данная строка работает и закрывает это окно по клавише ОК
```

---

`dlg.print_control_identifiers()` по этому окну выдаёт следующее.

```
Control Identifiers:

TfmTblWTP2 - 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"'    (L-8, T-8, R1928, B1048)
['Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TfmTblWTP2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"', 'TfmTblWTP2']
child_window(title="Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"", class_name="TfmTblWTP2")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L0, T1001, R1920, B1040)
   | ['Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"Static', 'Static', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   | child_window(class_name="TPanel")
   |    | 
   |    | TBitBtn - '&OK'    (L1835, T1009, R1910, B1034)
   |    | ['&OKTBitBtn', 'TBitBtn', '&OK']
   |    | child_window(title="&OK", class_name="TBitBtn")
   | 
   | TBitBtn - '&OK'    (L1835, T1009, R1910, B1034)
   | ['&OKTBitBtn', 'TBitBtn', '&OK']
   | child_window(title="&OK", class_name="TBitBtn")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L0, T48, R1920, B1001)
   | ['', 'Static2', '0', '1']
   | child_window(class_name="TPanel")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxGrid - ''    (L1, T49, R1919, B1000)
   |    | ['2', 'TcxGrid']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxGrid")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxGridSite - ''    (L3, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    |    | ['3', 'TcxGridSite']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxGridSite")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    |    |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxGridSite - ''    (L3, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    | ['3', 'TcxGridSite']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxGridSite")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   | 
   | TcxGrid - ''    (L1, T49, R1919, B1000)
   | ['2', 'TcxGrid']
   | child_window(class_name="TcxGrid")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxGridSite - ''    (L3, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    | ['3', 'TcxGridSite']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxGridSite")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   | 
   | TcxGridSite - ''    (L3, T51, R1917, B998)
   | ['3', 'TcxGridSite']
   | child_window(class_name="TcxGridSite")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   |    | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   |    | 
   |    | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   |    | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   | 
   | TcxSizeGrip - ''    (L795, T403, R812, B420)
   | ['4', 'TcxSizeGrip']
   | child_window(class_name="TcxSizeGrip")
   | 
   | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L1900, T51, R1917, B998)
   | ['TcxControlScrollBar', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar', 'TcxControlScrollBar0', 'TcxControlScrollBar1', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar0', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar1']
   | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   | 
   | TcxControlScrollBar - ''    (L3, T403, R795, B420)
   | ['TcxControlScrollBar2', 'Табель для руководителей подразделений - 22.11.2018 - 22.11.2018___"TcxControlScrollBar2']
   | child_window(class_name="TcxControlScrollBar")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L0, T23, R1920, B48)
   | ['5', 'Static3']
   | child_window(class_name="TPanel")
   |    | 
   |    | TToolBar - 'ToolBar'    (L1, T24, R1919, B53)
   |    | ['ToolBar', 'TToolBar', 'ToolBarTToolBar']
   |    | child_window(title="ToolBar", class_name="TToolBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Edit - ''    (L247, T24, R403, B46)
   |    |    | ['6', 'Edit']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TEdit")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TDBNavigator - ''    (L1, T24, R113, B46)
   |    |    | ['7', 'TDBNavigator']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="TDBNavigator")
   |    | 
   |    | Edit - ''    (L247, T24, R403, B46)
   |    | ['6', 'Edit']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TEdit")
   |    | 
   |    | TDBNavigator - ''    (L1, T24, R113, B46)
   |    | ['7', 'TDBNavigator']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TDBNavigator")
   | 
   | TToolBar - 'ToolBar'    (L1, T24, R1919, B53)
   | ['ToolBar', 'TToolBar', 'ToolBarTToolBar']
   | child_window(title="ToolBar", class_name="TToolBar")
   |    | 
   |    | Edit - ''    (L247, T24, R403, B46)
   |    | ['6', 'Edit']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TEdit")
   |    | 
   |    | TDBNavigator - ''    (L1, T24, R113, B46)
   |    | ['7', 'TDBNavigator']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TDBNavigator")
   | 
   | Edit - ''    (L247, T24, R403, B46)
   | ['6', 'Edit']
   | child_window(class_name="TEdit")
   | 
   | TDBNavigator - ''    (L1, T24, R113, B46)
   | ['7', 'TDBNavigator']
   | child_window(class_name="TDBNavigator")
```

`

Подскажите способ, как к ней обратиться или вызвать работающее сочетания клавиш.

## Обновлено. 23.11.2018

> Для начала стоит посмотреть, доступны ли тексты кнопок и само
>   количество кнопок ненулевое:

```
> toolbar = dlg.child_window(title="ToolBar",
> class_name="TToolBar").wrapper_object() print(toolbar.button_count()
> print(toolbar.texts())
```

Ошибка при вызове `print(toolbar.button_count())`

```
AttributeError: 'HwndWrapper' object has no attribute 'button_count'
```

Ответ от `print(toolbar.texts())` : `['ToolBar']`

---

> Если вообще ни одной кнопки не видно, возможно, стоит переключиться на
>   `backend="uia"`. Тут стоит посмотреть в Inspect.exe, что там видно.

При `backend="uia"`, не работает команда `dlg.TComboBox1.select("<Все>")`

```
app = Application(backend="uia")
app.start(r"C:\1\1.exe") # Запуск основной программы
dlg = app.window(title='Вход в систему') # Появляется окно авторизации
dlg.Edit1.set_edit_text("User")
dlg.Edit2.set_edit_text("GopTop")
dlg.OK.click()
dlg = app.window(title='1 - Учет рабочего времени')# Окно авторизации закрылось, открылось другое окно. Окно для ввода условий, что бы вывелась таблица.
dlg.TComboBox1.set_focus()
dlg.TComboBox1.select("<Все>")
```

Выдаёт ошибку `IndexError: item not found` , при использовании `backend="win32"` без проблем.

---

Ответ от Inspect при наведении на кнопку сохранения:

```
How found:  Mouse move (137,37)
    hwnd=0x0000000000D90982 32bit class="TToolBar" style=0x5600884E ex=0x10000
ChildId:    3
Interfaces: IEnumVARIANT IOleWindow IAccIdentity
Impl:   Local oleacc proxy
AnnotationID:   010000808209D900FCFFFFFF03000000
Name:   [null]
Value:  [null]
Role:   кнопка (0x2B)
State:  отслеженное (0x80)
Location:   {l:121, t:24, w:23, h:22}
Description:    [null]
Kbshortcut: [null]
DefAction:  "Нажать"
Help:   [null]
HelpTopic:  ""
ChildCount: 0
Window: 0xD90982
FirstChild: [null]
LastChild:  [null]
Next:   none : кнопка : обычный
Previous:   none : разделитель : обычный
Left:   none : разделитель : обычный
Up: [null]
Right:  none : кнопка : обычный
Down:   [null]
IsControlElement:   true
IsContentElement:   true
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   Container has no children
Ancestors:  "ToolBar" : панель инструментов : фокусируемое
    "ToolBar" : окно : фокусируемое
    none : клиент : фокусируемое
    none : окно : фокусируемое
    "Табель для руководителей подразделений - 23.11.2018 - 23.11.2018 __" : клиент : фокусируемое
    "Табель для руководителей подразделений - 23.11.2018 - 23.11.2018 __" : окно : изменяемого размера,перемеща
    "Рабочий стол 1" : клиент : фокусируемое
    "Рабочий стол 1" : окно : фокусируемое
    [ No Parent ]
```

### Проблема решена, благодаря ответу ниже.

Итоговое решения благодаря ответу:

```
# Распознавание тулбара не сработало, скажем ему явно обернуться тулбаром 
from pywinauto.controls.common_controls import ToolbarWrapper 
toolbar = ToolbarWrapper(dlg.child_window(title="ToolBar", class_name="TToolBar").wrapper_object().handle) 
print(toolbar.button_count() # получили ответ 6
toolbar.button(2).click() # при обращении к id = 2 произошёл нужное нам обращение.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала стоит посмотреть, доступны ли тексты кнопок и само количество кнопок ненулевое:

```
# Распознавание тулбара не сработало, скажем ему явно обернуться тулбаром
from pywinauto.controls.common_controls import ToolbarWrapper

toolbar = ToolbarWrapper(dlg.child_window(title="ToolBar", class_name="TToolBar").wrapper_object().handle)
print(toolbar.button_count()
print(toolbar.texts())
```

Если тексты есть:

```
toolbar.button("Save button text").click() # or .click_input()
```

Если текстов нет:

```
toolbar.button(index).click() # or .click_input()
```

Если вообще ни одной кнопки не видно, возможно, стоит переключиться на `backend="uia"`. Тут стоит посмотреть в Inspect.exe, что там видно.

Можно ещё по всплывающей подсказке искать кнопки:

```
toolbar.tip_texts()
toolbar.button("Save button text", by_tooltip=True).click()
```

Но это дольше будет работать, поскольку к каждой кнопке нужно подвести мышку и посмотреть tooltip. :)

Comment: Спасибо за Inspect.
Вот что он выдал, ответ от inspect, при наведении на кнопку, добавил в главное сообщение.

Comment: по ChildId можно как то обратиться к элементу? [class="TToolBar" style=0x5600884E ex=0x10000 | ChildId:    3]

Comment: В Инспекте стоит переключиться на режим UI Automation, а у вас MSAA стоит. И автоматический показ иерархии тоже удобен.

Comment: Нужно смотреть, поддерживается ли InvokePattern у кнопки. И какое свойство Name. Ещё AutomationId может есть. Ну, и традиционно `dlg.dump_tree()` (это алиас `dlg.print_control_identifiers()`).

Comment: Для изучения общей концепции: https://habr.com/company/yandex/blog/336476/

Comment: По поводу `"win32"` бэкенда - распознавание тулбара не сработало. Добавил в ответ явное создание ToolbarWrapper.

Comment: `# Распознавание тулбара не сработало, скажем ему явно обернуться тулбаром
from pywinauto.controls.common_controls import ToolbarWrapper

toolbar = ToolbarWrapper(dlg.child_window(title="ToolBar", class_name="TToolBar").wrapper_object().handle)
print(toolbar.button_count()
toolbar.button(2).click() # id =2`

Помогло, ответ `6`. И смог нажать на кнопку, id = 2.

Comment: Хорошо. В следующем релизе 0.6.6 будет автораспознавание такого тулбара.